# how can I make hbase region server listen on 0.0.0.0?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

My Hbase region server is listening on 127.0.0.1. How do I make it liste on 0.0.0.0 ? I tried channing value of hbase.regionserver.info.bindAddress but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to expose port 60020 on an external interface in (pseudo)distributed mode, HBase wants your /etc/hosts to look a certain way. If you run Ubuntu, you're likely to find something like this in your /etc/hosts: (I'm assuming your hostname is `regionserver`)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   regionserver
```

1. Select the a network interface with an IP address, e.g. eth0 with `192.168.1.2` and replace `127.0.1.1` with that address.
2. Edit the `hbase/conf/regionservers` to enter your hostname there.

   regionserver
3. Restart HBase and try to connect to port 60020 from a remote machine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thats great @oozie; Is there any other way to resolve this issue without an entry in 'hosts' file; I am working with HBase in windows os

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `hbase.regionserver.info.bindAddress`, you should employ `hbase.regionserver.ipc.address` property and set it to desired IP address or `0.0.0.0` mask. For example:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
```

Remember:

- this should be applied on each machine with Region Server running if you have a cluster instead of single machine.
- you have to restart Region Server component (not Master component) to apply the settings.
- all `*.info.*` properties are about web UI, not core functionality